# Почему не выкачиваются изменения с веток?

Tags: git, gitlab

В git-репозитории есть 3 ветки:

- vp
- dev
- master

vp - моя ветка.

Для выкачивания изменений использую следующие команды последовательно:

```
git checkout -b vp

git pull origin DEV

git pull origin master
```

Но изменения с веток не выкачиваются. В чем может быть проблема? В других ветках есть правки, но в локальный репозиторий они не выкачиваются.

Comment: Так вам надо же удаленную ветку получить. Сначала `fetch`, а потом просто `checkout vp` и потом `pull`. Предварительно удалите созданную локальную ветку `vp`

Comment: Можно по подробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: `git checkout -b vp` - создает новую локальную ветку и переключает на нее. `fetch` - получает список всех веток и устанавливает связь с `remote` ветками. Когда это произойдет, то вам надо просто переключиться на уже настроенную ветку `vp`: `git checkout vp` - по результатам сделать `git pull`, чтобы получить все новые изменения

Comment: Вам помогло это решить задачу?